# Get output of python script from within python script

Tags: python

printbob.py:

```
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

getbob.py

```
import subprocess
#printbob.py will always be in root of getbob.py
#a sample of sending commands to printbob.py is:
#printboby.py arg1 arg2 arg3   (commands are seperated by spaces)

print subprocess.Popen(['printbob.py',  'arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4']).wait()

x = raw_input('done')
```

I get:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
I just want to get the output of another python script inside of another python script.
Do I need to call cmd.exe or can I just run printbob.py and send commands to it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'printbob.py',  'arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print proc.communicate()[0]
```

There must be a better way of doing it though, since the script is also in Python. It's better to find some way to leverage that than what you're doing.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.STDIN
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'STDIN'

Comment: I had to seperate arg1 arg2 into different comman seperated strings like so `['python', 'printbob.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']`

Answer (score 7):

There is likely to be a better approach.

Consider refactoring `printbob.py` so that it can be *imported* by other Python modules. This version can be imported *or* called from the command-line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def main(args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Here it is called from the command-line:

```
python printbob.py one two three four five
printbob.py
one
two
three
four
five
```

Now we can import it in `getbob.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import printbob

printbob.main('arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4'.split(' '))
```

Here it is running:

```
python getbob.py 
arg1
arg2
arg3
arg4
```

See also [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/78845) for more detail of this Python idiom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a way to run python code not in the same instance... because of some thread odd behavior, but yes importing your scripts is normally the best way to access your code in another script.

Answer (score 4):

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use
>   the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is
>   recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence

Just wrap all arguments in a string and give `shell=True`

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("python myScript.py --alpha=arg1 -b arg2 arg3" ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print proc.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Worked for me perfectly (on Windows 10)!

Answer (score 4):

The `subprocess.run()` function was added in Python 3.5.

```py
import subprocess

cmd = subprocess.run(["ls", "-ashl"], capture_output=True)
stdout = cmd.stdout.decode()  # bytes => str
```

refer: [PEP 324 – PEP proposing the subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)