# How to read from linux terminal in python?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm using `subprocess.call('python simpletest.py',shell=True)` and it prints data to terminal so i want to catch this data, but i don't know how, nothing works. :(

Comment: You might want to reconsider your approach if you are using `subprocess` within python to invoke.... python.

Comment: If the external module you are calling is another Python script, then just import it and call the functions directly.

Comment: Another related post: [Get output of python script from within python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6086047/2745495)